# Como montar uma estrutura partindo da mesma estrutura?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho pesquisa muito uma forma de montar uma query no sql server mas não tenho obtido muito sucesso.

Primeiramente, tenho um sistema que controla pátio industrial no qual existe níveis organizacionais e tenho a estrutura que tem o nome do setor. O organizacional pode aumentar ou diminuir dependendo da demanda e estrutura tem uma relação de um para muitos com ela mesma.

Ex.:

```
> Organizacional {[Id: 1, Nm: Administracao], [Id: 2, Nm: Carregamento],
> [Id:3, Nm: Descarga], ...}
> 
> Estrutura {[Id: 1, Nm: XPTO, Organizacional_Id: 1], [Id: 2, Nm:
> Sementes, Organizacional_Id: 2], [Id: 3, Nm: Animal,
> Organizacional_Id: 2], [Id: 4, Nm: XPTO4, Organizacional_Id: 1], [Id:
> 5, Nm: Semente, Organizacional_Id: 3], ...}
```

Bom, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um query recursivo onde o resultado seria estrutura e o nome das colunas seria providos por organizacional

Ex.:

```
> [Organizacional.Nm]+'_Id',[Organizacional.Nm]+'_Nm' Estrutura.Id      
> , Estrutura.Nm
```

e assim por diante.

Comment: Terá que usar o Pivot, http://www.devmedia.com.br/pivot-no-sql-server-invertendo-linhas-e-colunas-em-um-exemplo-real/28318

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972%28v=sql.120%29.aspx , creio ser isto no sql server uso do CTE

Comment: Obrigado Motta e Tiago,
não consegui fazer da forma que desejava mas cheguei próximo. Utilizei o CTE para estrutura e o pivot para entrega do resultado.